# How to rapdily shift 10-bit intensities to top of 16-bit pixels?

Tags: c#, .net

I have an `UInt16[1000,1000]` array of 10-bit intensity values which I want shifted from bits 0-9 up six places to bits 6-15. What's a fast way to do this? Simply looping around all elements doing `i = i << 6` is too slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use direct access using pointers you use 32 or 64 bit integers and shift them. Should give the equivalent result but I expect it to be quite a bit faster(factor 2 or so). Another speedup should come from avoiding the complex indexing logic from accessing a 2D array.

Something like this:

```
fixed(UInt16* p0=&arr)
{
    UInt32* p=(UInt32*)p0;
    UInt32* p_end=p+1000*1000/(sizeof(UInt32)/sizeof(UInt16));
    while(p!=p_end)
    {
        *p = *p << 6;
    }
}
```

I assume in a 32 bit process 32 bit ints will be faster, and in a 64 bit process 64 bit ints will be faster.

You possibly might want to do some manual loop unrolling, i.e. put multiple assignments into one iteration of the loop.

You also might need to take special care of the end of the array. If the size of the array isn't a multiple of your chosen integer size.

Comment: Thanks. I'm hoping there's some native code library function that will give more than 2x.

Comment: @ChrisJJ How much faster did it get? The factor 2 was just a conservative estimate.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever solution you use can be speed up by using more than one thread.  Just don't lock the same object keep the data separate somehow.